# Paho Websocket Connection Closes Upon Second Connection

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, paho

I have built an MQTT server to test of M2M messages and I built a small Javascript application using Paho and I am able to connect, subscribe, and publish messages on a single connection. However, once I start up a new tab or browser, the first connection closes. I am not sure why and I happen when I have a new connection, even from another computer.

Comment: Are the other tabs/browsers connected to your MQTT server as well?

Comment: I have tried connection from a different computer and it closed the connection on the other computer. At first I thought it was because I was using the same browser connecting to the same server.

Comment: Do you have your javascript client set up to make a unique client ID for each connection? If not your server could be dropping the old connections while taking in the new ones only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use hard coded client ids, the best option is to use a random number or millisecond timestamp based id.

e.g.

```
var clientID = "web" + new Date().getTime();

var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client('localhost',1884,clientID);
```